# Isomorphic Definitions of Induced Representation

Tags: representation-theory

From Serre's book on Representation theory:

Given groups $H\le G$ and a representation of $H$, call it $W$, there are two (or three) ways to define the induced representation:
$$
V=\bigoplus_{\sigma\in G/H}W_\sigma,
$$
where $W_\sigma=\rho_sW$ for any $s\in\sigma$. The other way is to define:
$$
V=\mathbb{C}[G]\otimes_{\mathbb C[H]}W.
$$
These two, of course are isomorphic. But what is the **explicit** isomorphism (map) between them?

Moreover, there's a third way to define the induced representation, i.e.
$$
V=\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb C[H]}(\mathbb C[G],W).
$$
It seems even harder to show that $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb C[H]}(\mathbb C[G],W)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[G]\otimes_{\mathbb C[H]}W$. I have been thinking about this for a long while but failed to come up with a proof.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your "third way" is actually coinduction, not induction. These are isomorphic for finite groups but not in general (also you have to replace $\Bbb C[G]$ with $L^2G$ in general, IIRC). Are you familiar with tensor-hom adjunction? If you identify $\Bbb C[G]$ with its dual, you can interpret elements of $\Bbb C[G]\otimes_{\Bbb C[H]}W$ as elements of $\hom_{\Bbb C[H]}(\Bbb C[G],W)$.

Comment: Sorry I'm not very familiar with the tensor-hom adjunction. I'm seeking an explicit isomorphism between those two structures but I failed

Comment: If $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional vector spaces then $V^*\otimes W$ is isomorphic to  $\text{Hom}(V,W)$ thru a map arising via the universal property from
$$(\phi,w)\in V^*\times W \mapsto T_{\phi,w}\in \text{Hom}(V,W),
$$
where $T_{\phi,w}(v) =\phi(v)w$. This is the tensor-hom adjunction.

Comment: I'll look into your last question more carefully tomorrow.  But please tell me: are your groups finite?

Comment: Yes, they are finite!

Comment: @runway44, according to the method I am aware of, and in case representations are unitary, one must replace $\mathbb C[G]$, not with $L^2(G)$, but with $C^*(G)$, namely  the group $C^*$-algebra of $G$.

Comment: @Ruy This can be found in Borcherd's video on induced representation, at around 2min and 11min. It should work but I don't know how

Comment: @Zhuo.  I have edited,  adding an answer to your last question.

Comment: @runway44. I take it back.  The correct replacement for $L^2(G)$ is not $C^*(G)$, as I said before, but a mixture of both, in which functions are $L^2$ in "the direction of $H$" and $C^*$ in the "transverse direction". If you are interested I can give further details.  In any case it is inspired by what is sometimes called "Rieffel induction".

Comment: @Ruy That is such a comprehensive answer! Thank you again!

Comment: You are welcome. I suggest you read https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers to learn what to do when your questions are answered.

Comment: To people voting to close: this question is about a **single** mathematical construction (induced representation) and the OP is asking how to show that three apparently different definitions are equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose by the "elementary property of tensor products" you mean the "universal property of tensor products".  If so,
this is the main tool to produce homomorphisms whose domain is a tensor product space and I believe it is precisely what you need here!

Here is a brief definition of that property in a very special case, suitable for the present situation.  Suppose you have
a ring $R$  (e.g. $R={\mathbb C}[G]$, as  in the question), a subring $S\subseteq R$ (e.g. $S={\mathbb C}[H]$), and $W$, a left $S$-module.  Then the
tensor product $R\otimes _SW$ is a left $R$-module satisfying the following "universal" property:

1. There is a map
   $$
     \beta :R\times W\to R\otimes _SW,
     $$
   (think $(r,w)\mapsto r\otimes w$) which is (a) $R$-linear in the first variable,  (b) additive in the
   second variable, and (3) balanced,  meaning that  $\beta (rs,w)= \beta (r,sw)$, for all $r\in  R$, $s\in  S$, and $w\in W$.
2. For every $R$-module $Z$, and for every map
   $$
     \gamma :R\times W\to Z
     $$
   satisfying (a), (b) and (c), as above, there exists a unique
   $R$-linear map $\tilde \gamma :R\otimes _SW\to Z$, such that $\gamma =\tilde \gamma \circ \beta $.

(In a more general situation, namely when, in addition, $U$ is an $R$-$S$-bimodule, the above generalizes to a similar universal
property regarding the tensor product $U⊗_SW$.)

This applies to give a concrete map
$$
  \tilde \gamma : \mathbb{C}[G]\otimes_{\mathbb C[H]}W \to  \bigoplus_{\sigma\in G/H}W_\sigma,
  $$
starting with
$$
  \gamma : \mathbb{C}[G]\times W \to  \bigoplus_{\sigma\in G/H}W_\sigma,
  $$
defined by $\gamma (g,w)=\rho _sw$, viewed as lying in the direct summand $W_\sigma$.

Perhaps you can take it from here?

---

$\newcommand\sb[1]{_{#1}}$ EDIT:
Here is the isomorphism between the second and third definitions of induced representation.  Of course this will in
turn lead to an isomorphism between these and the first form (I must say that I try to avoid the first form given its
weird dependence on  left coset  representatives).

So $H$ is a subgroup of the finite group $G$,  we are given  a representation $W$ of $H$, and we want to find a $G$-covariant isomorphism
$$
  \Lambda :\text{Hom}\sb{{\mathbb C}[H]}({\mathbb C}[G],W) \to  {\mathbb C}[G]\otimes \sb{{\mathbb C}[H]}W.
  $$
We now need to choose a system of representatives of left cosets, say
$$
  R=\{g_1,\ldots , g_n\}
  $$
(despite what I said above).  This means that, for every $g$ in $G$, there exists a unique $r$ in $R$ such that $gH=rH$.

For each $\varphi $ in $\text{Hom}\sb{{\mathbb C}[H]}({\mathbb C}[G],W)$ we then define
$$
  \Lambda (\varphi ) = \sum_{r\in R}r\otimes \varphi (r^{-1}).
  $$
It is important to notice that the map $\Lambda $ itself does not depend on the choice of $R$.  In fact,
if $f,g\in  G$, and $fH=gH$, then
$$
  f\otimes \varphi (f^{-1})=g\otimes \varphi (g^{-1})
  $$
because we may write $f=gh$, for some $h\in  H$, and then
$$
  f\otimes \varphi (f^{-1})=  gh\otimes \varphi (h^{-1}g^{-1})=g\otimes h\varphi (h^{-1}g^{-1})=g\otimes \varphi (g^{-1}),
  $$
where we have used that the tensor product is balanced in the second step, and the fact that $\varphi $ is ${\mathbb C}[H]$-linear in the
last one.

Let us now show that $\Lambda $ is $G$-covariant (meaning that it is ${\mathbb C}[G)$-linear).  Given $\varphi $ in
$\text{Hom}\sb{{\mathbb C}[H]}({\mathbb C}[G],W)$, recall that for every $a\in  {\mathbb C}[G]$, according to the definition of the ${\mathbb C}[G)$-module
structure, $a\cdot \varphi $ is given by
$$
  (a\cdot \varphi )(x) = \varphi (xa), \quad \forall x\in  {\mathbb C}[G].
  $$
In the special case that $a=g\in G$, we have
$$
  \Lambda (g\cdot \varphi ) =
  \sum_{r\in R}r\otimes (g\cdot \varphi )(r^{-1}) =
  \sum_{r\in R}r\otimes \varphi (r^{-1}g) = \cdots
  $$
As noted above, the definition of $\Lambda $ doesn't depend on the choice  of representatives, so we opt for a new set, namely
$$
  R'=gR=\{gg_1,\ldots , gg_n\}.
  $$
The above then equals
$$
  \cdots =
  \sum_{r\in R'}r\otimes \varphi (r^{-1}g) =
  \sum_{r\in R}gr\otimes \varphi ((gr)^{-1}g) =
  g\sum_{r\in R}r\otimes \varphi (r^{-1}) = g\Lambda (\varphi ),
  $$
as desired.  Since $G$ spans ${\mathbb C}[G]$, this proves that $\Lambda $ is ${\mathbb C}[G]$-linear.

In order to prove that $\Lambda $ is bijective, we explicitly exhibit  its inverse.  For this it is convenient to introduce the
so called conditional expectation
$$
  E: {\mathbb C}[G] \to  {\mathbb C}[H],
  $$
namely the canonical projection given by
$$
  E\Big (\sum_{g\in  G}\lambda _g \ g\Big )=\sum_{g\in  H}\lambda _g\ g.
  $$
Two relevant properties of $E$ which we will need in what follows are:

1. $E$ is a ${\mathbb C}[H]$-${\mathbb C}[H]$-bimodule map,
2. If $R$ is a set of representatives, as above, then
   $$
     a=\sum_{r\in  R} rE(r^{-1}a) = \sum_{r\in R}E(ar)r^{-1},\quad \forall a\in  {\mathbb C}[G].
     $$

Since the domain of the inverse of $\Lambda $ is a tensor product module, we make use of the universal property and hence
we first define
$$
  \beta : {\mathbb C}[G]\times W \to  \text{Hom}\sb{{\mathbb C}[H]}({\mathbb C}[G],W)
  $$
by
$$
  \beta (a,v) : x\in  {\mathbb C}[G] \mapsto  E(xa)v\in  W,
  $$
for all $(a,v)\in  {\mathbb C}[G]\times W$.  Letting $\gamma $ be the corresponding map defined on ${\mathbb C}[G]\otimes \sb{{\mathbb C}[H]}W$, we have for all $a\otimes v$ in
${\mathbb C}[G]\otimes \sb{{\mathbb C}[H]}W$ that
$$
  \Lambda (\gamma (a\otimes v))=
  \sum_{r\in R}r\otimes \gamma (a\otimes v)|_{r^{-1}} = $$$$ =
  \sum_{r\in R}r\otimes E(r^{-1}a)v =
  \sum_{r\in R}rE(r^{-1}a)\otimes v = a\otimes v.
  $$
This shows that   $\Lambda \circ \gamma $ coincides with the identity on ${\mathbb C}[G]\otimes \sb{{\mathbb C}[H]}W$.  Regarding the composition
$\gamma \circ \Lambda $, pick $\varphi $ in $\text{Hom}\sb{{\mathbb C}[H]}({\mathbb C}[G],W)$ and $x$ in ${\mathbb C}[G]$.  then
$$
  \gamma (\Lambda (\varphi ))|_x =
  \sum_{r\in R}\gamma (r\otimes \varphi (r^{-1}))|_x =
  \sum_{r\in R}E(xr)\varphi (r^{-1}) =
  \varphi \Big (\sum_{r\in R}E(xr)r^{-1}\Big ) = \varphi (x),
  $$
so $\gamma \circ \Lambda $ is also the identity.

Comment: I see, so the map gamma(tilde) is similarly given by g⊗w ↦ ρ_s(w), where s is chosen from the coset in which g lies. Is that correct?

Comment: That is exactly how it works!

Comment: Regarding your comment, $g\otimes w$ is nothing but a different notation for $\beta(g,w)$, so what you just said, namely
that $\tilde\gamma $ maps $g\otimes w\mapsto \rho_s(w)$ is exactly the same as saying that $\tilde\gamma$ maps $\beta(g,w)$ to
$\gamma (g, w)$, or $\tilde\gamma\circ\beta=\gamma$, which is what we have above!

Comment: Thank you! I happen to have another question that I've been thinking for a while but unable to solve. Say V is induced by W using the tensor product definition above. There's another definition of induced representation, i.e. V = Hom(C[G], W) over C[H]. I can't see why these are canonically isomorphic. (If you want I can typeset the problem in the question again)

Comment: I have editted the question!